# How to select a bit based on value in another tables column in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2012

What I want to do is use a SELECT statment and have 2 columns selected, one of which will be a generated bit depending on a Join'ed tables column value.

```
SELECT [User].Id, 0 --this bit must change depending on Rule.Id 
FROM [dbo].[User] User
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Rule] Rule
ON [Rule].Id = 8
WHERE [User].UserId = @userId
AND [User].ShopId = @shopId
```

So if Rule.Id = 8 then the bit must be 1
if Rule.Id = 5 then bit is 0 otherwise bit is 0

Comment: Tagged with mysql. Are you sure?

Comment: SELECT rule.id = 8 my_bit FROM my_table

Comment: It says the multi-part identifier could not be bound

Comment: ok thanks , edited original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion:

```
SELECT [User].Id,case when  Rule.Id = 8 then 1 when  Rule.Id = 5 then 0 else 0 end  as bit
FROM [dbo].[User] User
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Rule] Rule
ON [Rule].Id = 8
WHERE [User].UserId = @userId
AND [User].ShopId = @shopId
```

Comment: why join on the rule?

Comment: Because the query requires rules.id.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server you can use the CASE function

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

```
SELECT [User].Id, Case Rule.id when 8 Then 1 Else 0 End as MyBit FROM [dbo].[User] User INNER JOIN  dbo].[Rule] Rule ON [Rule].Id = 8 WHERE [User].UserId = @userId AND [User].ShopId = @shopId
```